# Access POST values sent by Ajax in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using Ajax to get POST values from a form. However, when I try to insert the form values in a database on submit, it doesn't get inserted. I still have no idea why it does not work.

Here is my HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" id="home-sign-up-form">
    <input type="text" name="suFirstName" placeholder="First Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-first-name-text-input">
    <input type="text" name="suLastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-last-name-text-input">
    <input type="text" name="suEmail" placeholder="Email" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-email-text-input">
    <input type="password" name="suPassword" placeholder="Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-password-text-input">
    <input type="password" name="suConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-confirm-password-text-input">
    <input type="text" name="suDisplayName" placeholder="Display Name (you can change this later)" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-display-name-text-input">
    <br><font class="text-error" id="sign-up-error-text"></font><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="suRememberMe" value="yes" id="sign-up-remember-me-checkbox"><font id="sign-up-remember-me-text">Remember me</font></label>
    <input name="signUp" type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="sign-up-submit">
</form>
```

My JS (the first console.log does go through and work):

```
if (validForm)
{
    console.log("valid form");
    console.log(JSON.stringify($('#home-sign-up-form')[0].seriaize()));
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'POST',
        url:'form-submit.php',
        data:$('#home-sign-up-form')[0].serialize(),
        success:function(response)
        {
            $suForm.hide();
            $tosppText.hide();
            $mailSentIcon.show();
            $emailSentText.show();
            $emailSentTextEmail.text($suEmail);
            $suBox.css("padding-left", "10px");
            $suBox.css("padding-right", "10px");
        }
    });     
}
```

And my PHP/MySQL:

```
<?php require 'dbconnect.php'; ?>
if (isset($_POST['suEmail']))
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('got');</script>";
    $suFirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suFirstName']); 
    $suLastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suLastName']); 
    $suEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suEmail']); 
    $suPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suPassword']);
    $suDisplayName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suDisplayName']);
    $code = substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,15);

    $query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,email,password,displayName,confirmCode,verified)Values('{$suFirstName}','{$suLastName}','{$suEmail}','{$suPassword}','{$suDisplayName}','{$confirmCode},'{$verified}')");
}
```

The alert in the PHP code so I would assume that it isn't getting the 'signUp' POST variable. Thanks so much! Any help is appreciated! :D

Comment: put a `console.log(response)` as the first line of the success callback to see what you are getting back (if anything) ... also add some error handling ... check browser console for any errors on the request (i.e., basic debugging)

Comment: `the first console.log does go through and work` - what about the second one

Comment: Your sql insert is not working as php code ,coz you enclose `?>` in first line

Comment: @DavidJorHpan, I have php tags, I just left them out initially and then added the first line to show that I do have a connection file. Thanks anyways!

Comment: There is no index need for `serialize` so remove `[0]` index and run it . `$('#home-sign-up-form').serialize()` @RussellC.

Comment: did you try to var_dump($_POST); ? also if you missed a column that is not allow null make sure to allow null them. also check properly the data type of your column. example if your value is string the datatype must be string

Comment: @DavidJorHpan Hi! Thanks so much! It goes through the isset condition (I added a test echo) however I dont think the query works. It's not appearing in the database. Thanks so much!

Comment: @NewbeeDev I checked all of the data types and set them all to allow null, however it still doesn't work. Thanks so much!

Comment: try displaying the query echo "INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,email,password,displayName,confirmCode,verified)Values('{$suFirstName}','{$suLastName}','{$suEmail}','{$suPassword}','{$suDisplayName}','{$confirmCode},'{$verified}')"; and manually execute it in you phpmyadmin

Comment: and also I don't seen here where did you trigger the submit event

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#home-sign-up-form").submit(function(event) {
  alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'form-submit.php',
    data: $('#home-sign-up-form').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      var data = JSON.parse(response);
      $suForm.hide();
      $tosppText.hide();
      $mailSentIcon.show();
      $emailSentText.show();
      //$emailSentTextEmail.text($suEmail);
      $emailSentTextEmail.text(data.suEmail);
      $suBox.css("padding-left", "10px");
      $suBox.css("padding-right", "10px");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="home-sign-up-form">
  <input type="text" name="suFirstName" placeholder="First Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-first-name-text-input">
  <input type="text" name="suLastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-last-name-text-input">
  <input type="text" name="suEmail" placeholder="Email" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-email-text-input">
  <input type="password" name="suPassword" placeholder="Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-password-text-input">
  <input type="password" name="suConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-confirm-password-text-input">
  <input type="text" name="suDisplayName" placeholder="Display Name (you can change this later)" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-display-name-text-input">
  <br><font class="text-error" id="sign-up-error-text"></font>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="suRememberMe" value="yes" id="sign-up-remember-me-checkbox"><font id="sign-up-remember-me-text">Remember me</font>
  </label>
  <input name="signUp" type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="sign-up-submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['suEmail']))
{
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","cakpep","backoffice");

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    $suFirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['suFirstName']);
    $suLastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['suLastName']);
    $suEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['suEmail']);
    $suPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['suPassword']);
    $suDisplayName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['suDisplayName']);
    $code = substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,15);

    $query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,email,password,displayName,confirmCode,verified)Values('{$suFirstName}','{$suLastName}','{$suEmail}','{$suPassword}','{$suDisplayName}','{$confirmCode},'{$verified}')");
    echo json_encode($_POST);
}
?>
```

- add this to trigger when submit form 
  **$("#home-sign-up-form").submit(function(event) {**
- and then on php return the response with json string
  **echo json_encode($_POST);**
- and then in the response ajax parse json text to object like this 
  **var data = JSON.parse(response);
  $emailSentTextEmail.text(data.suEmail);**
- i hope this what you want..